# When should I switch from Symfony EventDispatcher to RabbitMQ (any *MQ library)?

Tags: symfony, events, rabbitmq, event-dispatching, symfony-eventdispatcher

What I am currently thinking about is that on our platform, number of events generated by users encreases every day (call started, call ended, call record ready, user blocked etc), so **when should be the right time to switch from Symfony EventDispatcher to something more efficient, scalable?**

Correct me please if I am wrong: Symfony EventDispatcher loads every subscriber into the server RAM and holds it until the request is being processed? If yes, that means that 2 generated events will occupy 2x(sum of all subscriber classes) memory in RAM, that will lead me to increasing server RAM and that will lead me to paying more instead of using efficient methods of event processing (libs, system architecture etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO  main reason to switch to MQ should be high code  execution  time .

If you  have a lot of  events (with for example  operations  on database) then your  execution time goes up .

Events are fired up inside  request->response, and  with MQ you can put it outside your application ,  that means that you will have better  execution time , but all events  operation will be  working "on background" - so it won' be "real time".

Personally i never seen high ram usage that  comes  directly form subscribers/listeners- even in some big projects.